# Modifying Spring Boot beans in Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, apache-camel

I am trying to create GraphQL mutation via Apache Camel GraphQL component. I know some basics of Spring Boot, however I haven't been working with it that much.

Everything works fine for the following code. But when I try to change the bean variable (JsonObject), I've discovered that I can't really change them programmatically. Can you please suggest me something to make it work?

```
@Bean
public JsonObject addProductMutationVariables() {
    JsonObject variables = new JsonObject();
    variables.put("sku", "sku001");
    variables.put("title", "Product 001");
    return variables;
}
```

```
rest().get("/api/demo")
    .to("direct:hello");

from("direct:hello")
    .process(new MyProcessor())            
    .to("graphql://https://api-url/graphql?queryFile=productcreate.graphql&variables=#addProductMutationVariables&accessToken=Token");
```